# Redirect route after login using nuxt auth module

Tags: vue.js, authentication, web, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I use nuxt auth module when I route to a guard page when I don't log in the login page is open but if I don't log in and go to another page not guarded and login successfully, automatically redirect me to the last guarded page I was open before if there is any solution for that? I want to go to the last page I was open after login successfully

Comment: Without seeing any code examples we might be guessing in the dark